# VBA Excel Formula Quotationmarks

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i am having some trouble with VBA.
Im trying to write a formula in a cell like this

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("I3").Formula = "=IF(H3<TODAY();" & Chr(34) & "closed" & Chr(34) & ";IF(G3>TODAY();" & Chr(34) & "open" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & "in stock" & Chr(34) & "))"
```

I think the problem lies with the quotationmarks. It is giving me the Error message Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.
Thank you in advance

Comment: replace the `;` with `,` vba is american english format.

Comment: remove the Chr(34) and change the `;` with `,`.

Comment: Change to `,` instead of `;` as a list delimiter or use `.FormulaLocal`. VBA is very EN-US-centric.

Comment: _escape_ double quotes by doubling up like so `debug.print     "=IF(H3<TODAY();""closed"";IF(G3>TODAY();""open"";""in stock""))"`  .... print this ...`=IF(H3<TODAY();"closed";IF(G3>TODAY();"open";"in stock"))`

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize all that has been said and to provide a working solution:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("I3").Formula = "=IF(H3<TODAY()," & """closed""" & ",IF(G3>TODAY()," & """open""" & "," & """in stock""" & "))"
```

Changes:

1. exchange the `;` with `,` (as noted by @ScottCraner) since VBA formulas have to be entered in American English format.
2. remove the `Chr(34)` and instead use two `"` inside the strings to insert one `"` effectively when the formula is written by VBA. Since strings themselves start with a `"` this results each time in three consecutive `"`.

### Update:

<sub>(as proposed in the comment)</sub>

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("I3").Formula = "=IF(H3<TODAY(),""closed"",IF(G3>TODAY(),""open"",""in stock""))"
```

Comment: Or without the ampersands:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("I3").Formula = "=IF(H3<TODAY(),""closed"",IF(G3>TODAY(),""open"",""in stock""))"